# What do you do after you complete a Nuzlocke in Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-series

After you beat the champion of whatever game you're playing in Pokemon, what do you do? I know in a Nuzlocke you can't revive you're pokemon, but there's no reason NOT to now. The game is over now.
Do you delete your save file?
Or if you want to keep playing in a Nuzlocked save file, do you have to keep going by Nuzlocke rules?
Ive never tried a Nuzlocke before, but I've watched other people do it. So I'm confused on what you're supposed to do after the game is over.

Comment: Maybe try "what *can* you do after"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Pokémon Nuzlocke challenge is a self-imposed challenge, meaning that there is no direction that the game outright forces you towards. After you reach your self-imposed goal you're free to play however you see fit. If you desire, you no longer have to adhere to the challenge's rules after defeating all gym leaders.

Because the Nuzlocke challenge is self-imposed there are no repercussions for breaking its rules.